# How to properly ignore objects with expectWeaklyReachable

Tags: leakcanary

One of third party SDKs causes memory leaks in my app by keeping references to two different Activities. I am trying to ignore these leaks with `expectWeaklyReachable`, this is my setup:

This is my setup:

```
val ignoredClasses = listOf(
    "com.example.MyLeakingActivity",
    "com.example.MyLeakingActivity2"
)

val watchersToInstall = AppWatcher.appDefaultWatchers(application, object : ReachabilityWatcher {
    override fun expectWeaklyReachable(watchedObject: Any, description: String) {
        if (ignoredClasses.contains(watchedObject::class.java.name)) return
        AppWatcher.objectWatcher.expectWeaklyReachable(watchedObject, description)
    }

})
AppWatcher.manualInstall(
    application = application,
    watchersToInstall = watchersToInstall
)
```

The problem is that with this configuration LeakMemory reports memory leaks for all Fragments and ViewModels inside these activities!! (because their host Activity is still around in the memory). I would have to provide a really extensive ignore list of all Fragments and ViewModels which can be used inside these activities.

How can I setup LeakCanary to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably name and shame the 3rd party SDK and get them to fix their leaks.

In the meantime, one workaround could be:

- If watchedObject is an instance of `View`, call `View.getContext()` and check if that's an instance of the bad activities.
- If watchedObject is an instance of `Fragment`, call `Fragment.getActivity()` and check if that's an instance of the bad activities.